# how to prevent react-datepicker from pushing inline elements to new line on toggle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

When using [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) with 2 adjacent elements, the second element gets pushed to the next row during the first element's click event.

### Before:

[image: Before]

### After:

[image: After]

### MRE:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

const DateRangeInput = () => (
    <>
        <DatePicker />
        <DatePicker />
    </>
);
```

I've tried for hours with various css properties, but can't find something that works.  How can I prevent this?

Here is a [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-fast-b8no1?file=/src/App.js) and the [mre](https://b8no1.csb.app/).

Make sure to wait for "loaded" to appear on the screen (it takes a few seconds to compile).

Comment: Did you try : `max-width: value` in your `Fragement` ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin I just tried it, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Would you reproduce your code via [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: You can't add CSS to a Fragment... what element would that apply to in html?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin I updated the question with a sandbox link

Comment: @Dominik, by HOC that wrapped the component. I did not mean inline css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May using `flex` with `maxWidth` will be also helpful.

```
 export default function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>loaded</h1>
          <div style={{ display: "flex", maxWidth: "200px" }}>
            <DatePicker />
            <DatePicker />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Sandbox : [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-villani-clmmi?file=/src/App.js:147-357)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is just to disable tab loop

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>loaded</h1>
      <DatePicker enableTabLoop={false}/>
      <DatePicker enableTabLoop={false}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works in my tests:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

const DateRangeInput = () => (
    <div css={{
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr',
    }}>
        <div><DatePicker /></div>
        <div><DatePicker /></div>
    </>
);
```

Add your style in whatever way you like... I used emotion but you get the point.

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-mirzakhani-ivnpy) that implements the above in your codesandbox link. I converted the emotion styles to vanilla css so it fits with what you got there.

Comment: Why you wrapped `DatePicker` with `div` ?

Comment: Because otherwise the Datepicker will break out of the container and be multiple elements. This will contain it. I don't like div-soup as much as the next person but I see no way around it

Comment: this doesn't work on my machine, or in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-fast-b8no1?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Mate... you can only put two elements into the div... you added three and didn't wrap the Datepicker...

Comment: @Dominik I did when I was testing your code.  Here is a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-shaw-vvs9s?file=/src/App.js) with your code

Comment: Just FYI I used [emotion](https://emotion.sh) like I mentioned in my answer... I ported what emotion would do to pure css for ya ;)

Comment: @Dominik can you provide a link?  I don't know how to view forks xD

Comment: The link is in the answer... here for you again: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-mirzakhani-ivnpy